# PHP - only using RegExp, get LAST occurrence

Tags: php, regex

How is it possible only using RegExp, to get the portion `ZZ...` of string

> hello example A hello example B hello example C hello example D, ..., heLLo ZZ...

Just after the last occurrence of `hello`; but how without `explode()`, `preg_split()`, etc...?

Only using **one line of RegExp**?

```
$string = 'hello example A hello example B hello example C hello example D, ..., heLLo ZZ...';
preg_match('/(hello).*$/is', $string, $match);print_r($match);
preg_match('/(hello)$.*$/is', $string, $match);print_r($match);
preg_match('/["hello"]{1}.*/is', $string, $match);print_r($match);
```

I can't find out how to get my target: `ZZ...`
In words: Anything after the last `hello`

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way would be to go greedy,

```
.*heLLo\s*(.*)$
```

this searches for everything until the last `heLLo` (and any amount of whitespace, then captures the remainder.

https://regex101.com/r/dGhMe2/1/

PHP Usage:

```
$string = 'hello example A hello example B hello example C hello example D, ..., heLLo ZZ...';
preg_match('/.*heLLo\s*(.*)$/', $string, $match);
echo $match[1];
```

PHP Demo: https://eval.in/821764

An alternative approach:

```
$string = 'hello example A hello example B hello example C hello example D, ..., heLLo ZZ...';
preg_match('/.*heLLo\s*\K.*$/', $string, $match);
echo $match[0];
```

Regex Demo 2: https://regex101.com/r/dGhMe2/2/

Answer (score -2):

```
\b(?!.*hello)(.*)
```

you can try here ==> https://regex101.com/r/hAE9Zq/4

Comment: `ZZ...` won't be accessible on its own still. You only need 1 capture group, capture the second `.+`.

Comment: That's it! Try now!

Comment: Why the negative lookahead? That drops performance, drastically.

Comment: The `.*` does that. The negative lookahead is adding +600 extra steps to the processing. This now just looks like a merge of Sebastian Proske and my answer.

Comment: Good to know. Very instructive!